# How to check how much battery the data network is using?

Tags: battery, battery-life, data-connection

How do I check how much battery the data network is using? When I enter `Settings->About phone->Battery usage` I get the following:

- Voice calls
- Android OS
- Display
- Android System
- Dialer
- Cell standby
- Phone idle

Which one is hiding the data-connection part? Is there a way to figure out how much the data connectivity was?

I barely use Wi-Fi, but I'll be also happy to know where that is (if its separate from the connection through the cellular company). Using Android 2.3.5 on Galaxy S 2

I tried searching google, but it just gave me stuff about how to make the battery last longer, nothing about how to check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of a hack, inconvenient and I'm not even sure if it would work: Download Juice Defender, set it to always keep data disabled and later check how much battery it claims to have saved you.

As for the Wifi, on my Phone (Xperia Neo V, 2.3.?), it's a separate entry on the battery usage panel. Maybe you used it so little that it isn't even displayed (probably <0.5%)?

Comment: The Wi-Fi part is probably true. And thanks for the suggestion, but I got curious because tomorrow I'm going on a trip for 3 days, so I wondered how much it will save disabling it. So I won't have time for tomorrow, but maybe one day I'll try that. :)